# PySpark (Python): loading multiline records via SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I'm loading a text file that comes in TSV (tabular separated value) notation but without the key in each line. So one line indicates a specific variable and all following lines are the values for that variable until a new variable occurs.

Therefore I'm loading the file with a custom delimiter (in Jupyter Notebook Python 2.7 - Pyspark):

```
sheet = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    'sample.txt',
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': 'var::'}
)
```

My question is, what about the size of such a multiline record? The values for one single variable might be thousands of lines. Does Spark load the file at once on one single machine or does it split that block into smaller ones (chunks) that are then processed?

Just want to make sure that the memory is not exploding on the processing node. Thanks for any explanation.

[image: reading multiline records]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each (key, value) pair returned by `o.a.h.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat` is a single local data structure containing an offset (`long`) and string. There is no mechanism which can split value between multiple records without creating custom Hadoop [`InputFormat`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html).

"Thousands of lines" is not very precise description but as a rule of thumb:

- If on-disk size is less than a few megabytes you're most likely good to go.
- Otherwise you'll have to keep track of memory usage and GC and adjust configuration.

Also keep in mind that large records can result in suboptimal resource utilization. In the worst case scenario you can end up with a single record per task where cost of bookkeeping can be much higher than the actual execution.

Comment: a file of 170MB contains 50 multiline records that start with "Time" and 5.252.874 lines overall. So one record has about 106.000 lines. Maybe not a good idea to read that as a single block. Another option might be reading all files and remember the line-number at which "Time" occurred and re-read the file later on using that information to construct the key-timestamp-value triples.

Comment: Is it the same app as before?

Comment: Indeed. But I was testing with a small sample. The real data are about 70 to 170MB per file each.

Comment: It shouldn't be a huge issue. It gives what? 3.5MB per record? Slightly largish but nothing extraordinary.

Comment: I will check that out on Monday and let you know then. Other option might be the one mentioned above, saving the occurrences of "Time" in a global variable and use it while re-reading. Or writing an own [converter as mentioned here](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/09/17/spark-1-1-bringing-hadoop-inputoutput-formats-to-pyspark.html). But true, 3.5MB should be fine.

Comment: It worked fine, thanks. But if I'm not mistaken only one data-node is processing the files - instead of six.

Comment: With 170MB it is no surprising. It is roughly the same order of magnitude as typical input split.